# Dependency Inversion Principle's second statement elaboration

Tags: oop, design-patterns, solid-principles

Following two statements are core of the Dependency Inversion Principle(DIP):

"High-level modules should not depend on low-level modules. Both should depend on abstractions."
"Abstractions should not depend on details. Details should depend on abstractions."

I read different books and article about DIP; all of them explained the first statement but none of them explain the second statement: "Abstractions should not depend on details. Details should depend on abstractions". Please explain what exactly are the meaning of this second statement.

Comment: The second part is about leaky abstractions. To be a good abstraction, it should not leak implementation details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just means that you don't want to change an abstraction just because a detail has changed because details are likely to change.

Because both high-level and low-level modules depend on abstractions, they will also have to be changed whenever a detail has changed. This would obviously be undesirable.

Answer (score 2):

Don't decide on *interface (abstraction)*  by looking at *implementation (details)* first.

e.g. You can define a Repository interface. But while designing Repository interface, you should not decide on *interface (abstraction)*  by looking at specific solutions like *SQL implementation or NoSQL implementation ( details)*.

Let the Repository interface is generic and SQL features Or NoSQL feature implementation should be specific.

You will get clarity about the second statement if you read this [article](http://martinfowler.com/articles/dipInTheWild.html) by ***Martin Fowler***

> Switch out the repository for a different storage mechanism, there's no mention of SQL in its interface so we can use an in-memory solution, a NoSql solution or a RESTful service.

Answer (score 1):

You should think of "details" as "implementations":
- if you declare some interface, it does not depend on its future implementation classes.
- in the other hand, implementation classes should reference their interface and implement its methods, so they depends on it.